# UPDATE multiple values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm working in a table that holds a quite huge amount of entries, each one with multiple values.

I was asked to make a few edits to certain sub-sections of this table. The issue is that when I execute the script, every entry that already has one or more of the values in "SET" is ignored, even if other values are unmodified. For example, let's say that I have 40 entries that meet the conditions o this code:

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `value1` = "50" AND `value2` = "75" AND `value3` = "1800" AND `value4` = "81015" AND `value5` = "String here."
WHERE `condition1` = "2" AND `condition2` = "1" AND `condition3` = "1";
```

Out of those 40, 15 have their value2 equal to 75, but the rest do not match up. For some reason, those 15 entries aren't modified at all.

I am unsure if it's because of the software i'm using to handle the DB (SQLyog Community), or maybe it's the syntax.

How could I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to add: It's a MySQL DB.

Comment: If you forget something that you wanted to include in your question - say as another tag - you have an edit link at the bottom. You shouldn't ever need to (directly) comment to your own questions (using comments to reply to other comments is fine though, and expected)

Comment: I'm not a mySQL guy, but try

UPDATE `table1`
SET `value1` = "50", `value2` = "75", `value3` = "1800", `value4` = "81015", `value5` = "String here."
WHERE `condition1` = "2" AND `condition2` = "1" AND `condition3` = "1";

Is AND a valid delimiter between columns in an update?

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I was supposed to use commas instead of "ANDs".

Comment: Added as an answer, didn't want to risk it while it could be wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update fields should be delimited by commas, not AND keywords.

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET value1 = "50", 
    value2 = "75", value3 = "1800", value4 = "81015", value5 = "String here." 
WHERE 
    condition1 = "2" AND condition2 = "1" AND condition3 = "1";
```